Is there a way to protect the workbook in exceljs/sheetjs or in any other node library?
Even if I pass the workbook which is password protected, it still removes the protection on the workbook.
I want the sheet to not remove the protection on the workbook.
It doesn't remove protection on the sheet but it does remove on the workbook.

Does this help?

If you want to protect the formulae then just copy paste.special as values.
